# How to convert SQL Join query into LINQ?

Tags: linq, join

I need to convert this code into linq query.

The query below gives me to correct total in MS SQL.

```
SELECT SUM(t1.itemPrice + t2.itemPrice) as TOTAL FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 WHERE r.userID = u.userID
```

I am trying to get this same code to work in linq query so I can use it in my project MVC4.

My attempt is failing mainly b/c I am not very familiar with Linq just yet. here it is:

--Linq--

```
var query = (from t1 in db.table1 
             join table2 in db.table2 
             on t1.userID equals t2.userID
             select new { SUM (t2.itemPrice + t1.itemPrice) });
```

Obviously the above don't work. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

You are very close. `Sum()` has to be applied with non-Linq syntax:

```
var query = (from t1 in db.table1 
             join table2 in db.table2 
             on t1.userID equals t2.userID
             select t2.itemPrice + t1.itemPrice).Sum();
```

The sum operation will still be converted to SQL if possible, as you will be calling [`IQueryable.Sum()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.queryable.sum(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The other simple looking solution is:

```
var query = table1.Join(table2, x=>x.userID, y=>y.userID, (x,y) => (x.itemPrice + y.itemPrice)).Sum();
```

Comment: OOPS...I just realized that its giving me the wrong total. Because the query uses JOIN the SUM() is wrong. Example, say table1 1 row with the value of $60 and table2 has 2 rows one each with  value of 5. The above query returns a SUM of 130 (60 + 60 + 5 + 5). The correct answer should be 70 (60 + 5 + 5).

Comment: How can we use a UNION ALL? It seem to be returning the correct sum.
`select distinct t1.itemPrice from table1 t1
union all
select distinct t2.itemPrice from table2 t2`